# Java Regex Russian Initials

Tags: java, regex

```
О.Г.дов.
```

I'm trying to match the "О.Г ." in this fragment. Normally, initials should be without spaces, so I need a regex that can account for optional spaces.

I've been using:

```
[А-Я]\s*\.\s*[А-Я]\s*\.\s*
```

But it seems to not match this correctly. I'm unsure why.Note, I am typing `\\` in java before "s" and ".". Could someone spot an error?

Comment: Are you using `matches()`? Use `find()`, and add `^` at the start.

Comment: That worked, I'll have to look into the difference.Thank you!

Comment: `[А-Я]` does not include 1 Russian letter, do not forget to include it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regex to try:

"`([А-Я]\\s*\\.\\s*[А-Я]\\s*\\.)\\s*.*`"

### Explanation and sample code:

If Matcher finds a match for given regex, you get rid of all unnecessary spaces in captured group #1 (in the parenthesis `()`) and print it to the console:

```
String source = "О . Г . дов.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^[А-Я]\\s*\\.\\s*[А-Я]\\s*\\.)\\s*.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
if(m.find()) {
    String resultWithoutSpaces = m.group(1).replaceAll(" ", "");
    System.out.println(resultWithoutSpaces);
}
```

Output you get:

```
О.Г.
```

Comment: @dj1121 Glad that I could help - please have a look at my latest edit, I improved my answer to make it remove all unnecessary spaces from result initials.